# Can I run two python script using the same pi camera in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, pi-3b+, picamera

I am currently working on a project where I need to have a live stream video and a motion detection that when a motion is detected, records a 10 second video. I have put each functionality in different python files. I am using a single Pi camera. When I tried to run both programs at the same time, the second python file does not run. I just wanted to know if it is possible to run two programs simultaneously using a single pi camera. If it is possible, how? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `I got an error`

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second python file does not execute

Comment: You can only have one instance of the camera stack running, so you will have to combine the two functions.

Comment: @Dirk thanks for your reply. Yes, I'll do that.